# WPF Radio Button showing mouse over colour incorrectly

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have three Radio Buttons in a toolbar as part of a tab. When the tab is opened the first button always displays the mouse over colour - it goes away when the user clicks anywhere on the tab, and back again next time the tab is selected. I have tried to set the focus on other elements, nothing seems to stop this behaviour and it's very confusing for the user - in the screenshot below 'Statements' is selected

[image]

```
Dim NotUsedRB As New RadioButton
        With NotUsedRB
            .Content = "Not Used"
            .ToolTip = "This mailing address is not used"
            .GroupName = "MailingRB"
            .Name = "Mailing_NotUsedRB"
        End With
        RegisterControl(Customer_Grid, NotUsedRB)
        vToolbar.Items.Add(NotUsedRB)
        vToolbar.Items.Add(TS_Separator)

        Dim StatementsRB As New RadioButton
        With StatementsRB
            .Content = "Statements"
            .ToolTip = "Mailing address used for statements"
            .GroupName = "MailingRB"
            .Name = "Mailing_StatementsRB"
        End With
        RegisterControl(Customer_Grid, StatementsRB)
        vToolbar.Items.Add(StatementsRB)
        vToolbar.Items.Add(TS_Separator)

        Dim FinesRB As New RadioButton
        With FinesRB
            .Content = "Fines"
            .ToolTip = "Mailing address for violation fines"
            .GroupName = "MailingRB"
            .Name = "Mailing_FinesRB"
        End With
        RegisterControl(Customer_Grid, FinesRB)
        vToolbar.Items.Add(FinesRB)
        vToolbar.Items.Add(TS_Separator)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that setting .Focusable = False to all the Radio Buttons was the answer :-)